# Install RPM package with Python Yum API with --downloadonly

Tags: python, yum

I am trying to install/download an RPM package through the Yum API with Python. But I am not able to supply the `--downloadonly` option, it seems to be ignored by the `install` method.

Here is my code so far:

```
import yum

yb = yum.YumBase()
args = {"name":"git", "downloadonly": True}
yb.install(**args)
yb.processDeps()
yb.buildTransaction()
yb.processTransaction()
```

This will install the package on the system, but not honor the `downloadonly` option.

What is the proper way of telling Yum to only download a package through the Python Yum API?

Comment: This was definitely interesting. You can learn about the options by looking into the doc. http://yum.baseurl.org/api/yum/yum/__init__.html. You can also look at the python code : `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
import yum

yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.conf.downloadonly = True
args = {'name':'git'}
yb.install(**args)
yb.buildTransaction()
yb.processTransaction()
```

After executing this python script, you can find the downloaded package in

```
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/packages/
```

The path above may be different for you depending on the distro.

Comment: If you want to specify the download directory, set `yb.conf.downloaddir = '/your/directory'` and yum will place the file(s) there.  It seems like YumBase.conf uses the command-line options as the naming convention.